# Allowing a domain name in my IP Tables

Tags: linux, iptables, clock, ntp

I have a Linux server that gets a time offset for some strange reason. I set up cron job to run and update the time using the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

The problem is the command would not run because I have a firewall (iptables).

I have always used IP to allow traffic in my network:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 -s 11.11.11.11 --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
```

I would like to know how to do it using a domain name in this case would be `pool.ntp.org`, or maybe someone could tell me a better way to keep the clocks in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow a NTP client to talk to a server you can use these rules:

```
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

To act as a NTP server and accept client connections:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

#### References

- [What are the iptables rules to permit ntp?](https://superuser.com/questions/141772/what-are-the-iptables-rules-to-permit-ntp)